# Why is the OR operator used instead of AND operator in the select method?

Tags: ruby, logical-operators

Given a hash of family members, with keys as the title and an array of names as the values, use Ruby's built-in `select` method to gather only immediate family members' names into a new array.

```
# Given

family = {  uncles: ["bob", "joe", "steve"],
            sisters: ["jane", "jill", "beth"],
            brothers: ["frank","rob","david"],
            aunts: ["mary","sally","susan"]
          }
```

The solution is:

```
immediate_family = family.select do |k, v|
  k == :sisters || k == :brothers
end

arr = immediate_family.values.flatten

p arr
```

Why is `||` operator used instead of `&&` operator in the select method? When I run it with `&&`, the select method returns an empty array.

Comment: How can something be `:sisters` and `:brothers` at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||` and `&&` operators mean `or` and `and` respectively in most programming languages.

The expression:

```
family.select do |k, v|
  k == :sisters || k == :brothers
end
```

would translate into "select all elements of the `familiy` hash where the key is `:sisters` or `:brothers`". As @Ursus points out, in this case it doesn't make sense for `k` to be equal to `:brother` and `:sister` at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Think about it. Your `k` is a symbol and a symbol can't be both `:sisters` and `:brothers` at the same time, can it? So, with `&&` the block would never be true.

But in another contexts `&&` does the job. Let's say you want to filter out people with more than 20 years and less than 60.

```
people.select { |person| person.age > 20 && person.age < 60 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`&&` and `||` are logical operators:

- `a && b` is truthy if both, `a` and `b` are truthy
- `a || b` is truthy if `a` is truthy or if `b` is truthy (or both)

*truthy* (in Ruby) means everything but `nil` or `false`.

Let's see what happens, if `a` is `k == :sisters` and `b` is `k == :brothers`:

```
k           a       b       a && b   a || b
:uncles     false   false   false    false
:sisters    true    false   false    true
:brothers   false   true    false    true
:aunts      false   false   false    false
```

For the given values, `a && b` would always return `false`, whereas `a || b` would return `true` if `k` is `:sisters` or if `k` is `:brothers`. Which is what you want.